# How to Create a Cookieless Domain in Wordpress

Tags: domain, cookies

How do you create a ['cookieless' domain](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#cookie_free) for WordPress?

Answer (score 2):

Using "cookieless" domain for serving static assets is common recommendation performance tools give. The reasoning being that cookies do *nothing at all* for such files, but still consume resources.

It is, however, not something WP can handle for following reasons:

1. WordPress does not control domain. DNS points domain to specific server's IP address, where WP installation (configured accordingly) responds to requests.
2. WordPress does not work without cookies. They are necessary for authentication and without them you wouldn't be able to access WP administration area.

So creating such domain is a task that is both separate from WordPress and more so it should be *isolated* from WP installation, or it will add cookies and you are back to original issue.

Comment: Ok, I  get it that we cannot create a cookiless doamin and it is a bit tough to create  it.
But, when you google How to create a cookiless doamain for wordpress you'll find out that there are several suggestions and tutorials available.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create a new subdomain (static.example.com) on the same server and use .htaccess rules to serve the files located under the wordpress directories.

Now you need to write a plugin which will change the domain from which static content like images and JS  files  are served. You can do it by buffering the generated HTML page and before outputing it change all images that have `src="http://example.con...."` to `sec="http://static.example.com...."` and do the same for all the other static resources.

Does it worth the effort? by default wordpress cookies are relatively small and their removal will not have a big impact and on the con side you will have to "pay" for an additional domain name resolution for static.example.com. Might be worth it if you serve many static files but I don't remember seeing any benchmark that tests it.

Comment: The issue is that your web browser will only open so many connections at a time to each domain, and serialize access to those resources. Putting static resources on a cookieless subdomain, or even a subdomain that still serves cookies, will tend to improve performance because your browser will pull more remote assets concurrently.

Comment: @Craig, I don't think it is an actual concern for a long time. Modern browsers have 17+ connection at the same time. If the static domain was on a different server that is configured to serve static files it might end up as a win, but on the same server I doubt you will notice the difference.

Comment: Possibly, but there are also potential issues with the load on the server for a site with high traffic, and you might be surprised by the number of cookies returned for every asset. Everything on your site that sets a cookie, every analytics script, everything, will result in all those same cookies being returned redundantly for every asset requested.

Comment: basic packet size on the internet is 1.5k, and most likely higher than that. As long as the added data do not cause the packet to cross the boundary, and therefor avoids waiting for another packet, you will see no difference. Anyway, this answer explains exactly how to easily set a cookieless domain, could probably be expanded, but since I don't believe in the actual need for that in the context of wordpress site, I probably not going to do it ;)

Comment: basic packet size on the internet is most definitely 1.5k at an absolute maximum. Potentially quite a bit smaller for DSL users. The available data fills the packets to the brim. If there are two little images that are, say, 700 bytes each, they'll both transfer in one packet. It isn't really a matter of packet size, it's a matter of the overall volume of data. Which I agree is a smaller issue these days than it was in the past. By the same token, I've seen situations where just getting 304 responses for already-cached server resources drove performance through the floor (slow).

Comment: Honestly, one of the biggest things you can probably do to improve the performance of your site these days is to enable HTTPS and utilize HTTPS pipelining (HTTP/2). I'd wager that would provide a bigger bang for the buck than a cookieless domain for static assets.

Comment: sure http/2 is the way to go, but it is not like it is painless easy to do process if you serve different JS and CSS per page.... waiting for questions about how to do that, as for sure it is more relevant to site performance this days than cookieless domains :)

Comment: The underlying problem there is all the third-party analytics and advertising scripts...   :-p